# How to store a angular.js model variable in a javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I store let's say selectedSong.artist in a variable in my javascript code ? I want to do this so i can use this selected value as a search term in another function .   the {{selectedSong.artist}} epression is giving back a name , I want to put this name in a variable in my javascript.

```
  <div class="list-group-item col-md-12">
      <div class="col-md-6">
         <p>
            Titel : <select ng-model="selectedSong" ng-options="song as song.title for song in songs.tracks"></select>
         </p>
         <p>
            Artiest : <select ng-model="selectedSong" ng-options="song as song.artist.name for song in songs.tracks"></select>
         </p>
         <p>
            Tijdstip : <select ng-model="selectedSong" ng-options="song as (song.played_at | date: 'hh:mm') for song in songs.tracks">
             </select>
         </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
         <button class="btn-success btn-lg" ng-click="selectedSong = songs.tracks[0]">Het afspelende lied</button>
      </div> 
  </div>
```

Comment: If possible can you create plunker ?

Comment: I can make it more clear maybe , i'll edit my question

Comment: Yes it will be helpfull what do you want exactly means by 'my javascript code ' ?Do you want to store variable out of angular js ?

Comment: javascript means controller..??

Comment: You don't mean to use `$scope.selectedSong.artist` ? Do you ?

Comment: well i have a javascript file where all my functions are , and I want to use this {{selectedSong.artist}} string in those functions , so I want to make a var = (the artist name i recieved from the model) , that I can use in methods .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

selectedSong now lives in your controller (assuming there is a controller somewhere above this code). You can then use a $watch function to get that variable whenever it changes, or just reference it directly from your controller.

Here is a $watch example:

```
      $scope.$watch('selectedSong', function (newVal, oldVal) {
         if (newVal !== oldVal) {
            // Do something with newVal It will be selectedSong
         }
      });
```

Or just as a reference:

```
$scope.selectedSong
```

Comment: sure :) just be careful when using $watch. Using watches makes the app heavier, so don't use it often, only when you must.

Comment: And in this case it's not a must. If you need to `$watch` for a property inside your controller. You're probably doing it wrong.

Comment: I only want to use it to check if it is really showing the selected song but at this point it is not logging the result i made this function in my controller :         $scope.$watch('selectedSong', function (newVal, oldVal) {
                    if (newVal !== oldVal){
                        console.log($scope.selectedSong.artist);
                    };
                });

Comment: this function isn't doing annything atm :/